# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'outerWidth')　ーーBootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I code a function in javascript to realize booststrap table column size change when a button is clicked. But when I turn off the button, table column size cannot be changed.
The error on console is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'outerWidth')`. jquery.resizableColumns.js:178

How to solve this problem?
Thank you!

**html code:**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="{{ tooltip_messages.terminal.host_detail.disp_mode }}">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="disp_mode" onchange="redraw_host_detail();">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="disp_mode"></label>
</div>
...... ...... ......
...... ...... ......
...... ...... ......
<div id="device_list">
    <table id="host_detail_table" data-resizable="true"></table>
</div>
```

**javascript code:**

```
function redraw_host_detail() {
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "{% url 'ajax_tool1' %}",
            data: {
                "graph_id": 'host_detail',
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{csrf_token}}',
                "disp_mode": get_disp_mode(),  
                "sensor_type": get_target_sensor(),
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            if ($("#messages")) {
                $("#messages").html("");
            }
            if (response.messages) {
                $.each(response.messages, function (i, m) {
                    $(".page-tabs").after("<div id='messages'><div class='" + m.tags + "'>" + m.message + "</div></div>")
                });
            }. else {
                if (response.table_data) {
                    data = response.table_data;
                    columns = response.table_columns;
                    let config = {
                        rowStyle: rowStyle,
                    }
                    config.data = data;
                    config.columns = columns;                              
                    $('#host_detail_table').bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable(config);
                    $('#device_list').resizableColumns();
                }
            }
            init_tooltip();
        });
    });
}
```

I tried to modify it to $('#host_detail_table').resizableColumns();
But even the button is on, column size cannot be changed.

Comment: Add $('#device_list').resizableColumns('destroy'); before $('#device_list').resizableColumns(); and it is solved!